# AddEventListener is working at the wrong time

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

For some reason, the addEventListener is working both when it should work, and when it shouldn't work. I made a game where if the player hasn't lost, they play, but **only** when they lose, they can click on the screen to retry. In the browser, when the game is opened, or the browser is refreshed, everything works fine. However, after the first loss, any clicks cause the game to restart from the beginning. What am I doing wrong?

```
function main() {
  setTimeout(function everyFrame() {
    clearCanvas();
    //Run if the game isn't over
    if (!isGameOver()) {
      game_over = false;

      //Code for the game screen
    }

    //Run if the game is over
    else if (isGameOver()) {
      game_over = true;

      //Code for the lose screen

      //Reset the game when the user clicks on the lose screen
      if (game_over) {
        game_over = false;
        myCanvas.addEventListener("click", restartGame);
      }
    }
    main();
    changingDir = false;
  }, 100);
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you only want the event listener to work once. Maybe try `myCanvas.addEventListener("click", restartGame, {once:true});` See [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) for more info on the options like once

Comment: You are adding event listeners without removing them, so the second time the event is set even if game_over is false... this is the first thing i see, so for a fix you should add the event listener to myCanvas when it's created and add the logic there or remove the listener after click.

Comment: @David784 Thank you. That fixed the issue

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan it works out pretty fine, from what I've tested. What's wrong with it?

Comment: @Angel misread your code. All is fine, sorry